# How can I have a default sub view show up when I am using Angular ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states defined:

```
 var test = {
            name: 'test',
            url: '/test',
            views: {
                'page': {
                    templateUrl: '/Content/app/test/partials/page.html',
                },
            }
        }

        var testContent = {
            name: 'test.content',
            parent: 'test',
            url: '/:content',
            views: {
                'page-content': {
                    templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
                        var isNumber = !isNaN(parseFloat(stateParams.content));
                        return isNumber ? '/Content/app/test/partials/detail.html' :
                                          '/Content/app/test/partials/home.html'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In my HTML I have:

```
<article class="container_12" >
    <div data-ui-view="page"></div>
</article>
```

In my page.html I have:

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestPageController">
    <div class="grid_3">
        Menu stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="grid_9">
        <div data-ui-view="page-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way for my application to have the home.html display inside the page-content
when I just select the url: /test

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can put whatever you want inside a `ui-view`, and that'll be the default content.

Once you load a different view, it'll replace the default content:

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestPageController">
    <div class="grid_3">
        Menu stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="grid_9">
        <div data-ui-view="page-content">
            <div ng-include="/Content/app/test/partials/home.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```